# How make a union of two columns with different value of fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I Have two columns from different selects in sql server

**Table 1**

```
 ID     Name           Bit
....   ............   .....
 1     Enterprise 1   False 
 2     Enterprise 2   True
 3     Enterprise 3   False
```

**Table 2**

```
 ID       Name             Bit 
....    ............     .......
 1      Enterprise 1      True
 2      Enterprise 2      False
 3      Enterprise 3      False
```

**expected result**

```
ID       Name           Bit 
....   ............   ......
1      Enterprise 1    True
2      Enterprise 2    True
3      Enterprise 3    False
```

the problem is make a union between the two tables and the bit column prevail fields that are true

Any ideas?

Comment: Should the third record come from `Table 1` or `Table 2`? Can an Item have `True` in both tables, and which one should be used in that case?

Comment: tables from two different select , select are very long to post them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest casting it to an int:

```
select id, name, cast(max(bitint) as bit) as bit
from ((select id, name, cast(bit as int) as bitint
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select id, name, cast(bit as int) as bitint
       from table2
      )
     ) t12
group by id, name;
```

With your data, you can also do it using `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, (t1.bit | t2.bit) as bit
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name;
```

This assumes all the rows match between the two tables (as in your sample data).  You can do something similar with a `full outer join` if they don't.

Comment: missing t1 and t2 aliases in second option "from table1 t1 join table2 t2"

Comment: :) a pleasure. It was also a pleasing see the "bitwise OR" being used

Answer (score 1):

You can make a left join on the other table to exclude the records that should be used from the other table:

```
select
  t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Bit
from
  [Table 1] t1
  left join [Table 2] t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
where
  t1.Bit = 1 or t2.Bit = 0

union all

select
  t2.ID, t2.Name, t2.Bit
from
  [Table 2] t2
  left join [Table 1] t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID
where
  t1.bit = 0 and t2.Bit = 1
```

(If there is a `True` in both tables or a `False` in both tables for an item, the record from `Table 1` is used.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Name, IIF(Table1.[Bit]>0 OR Table2.[Bit]>0,1,0) AS [Bit]
FROM 
(VALUES(1,'Enterprise 1',0),(2,'Enterprise 2',1),(3,'Enterprise 3',0)) as Table1(ID,Name,Bit),
(VALUES(1,'Enterprise 1',1),(2,'Enterprise 2',0),(3,'Enterprise 3',0)) as Table2(ID,Name,Bit)
WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

It seems to me that you are just doing a logical OR operation on the Bit column and calling it UNION.

[image: Query Result]